# laravel の $request->user() という routeing の処理はどこに書かれていますか

Tags: laravel

PHP 自体はわかるんですが laravel に触れたことがなく
担当者が夏休みで急遽作業しなければならなくなったんですが
routing が読めずにどのファイルに処理が書かれているかわからず困っています

route/api.php というファイルに

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

というのが書かれていてこれが GET /api/user を叩いたときの処理だと思うのですが（ここも自信ありません）

```
$request->user();
```

というのが次にどのファイルに飛んでいるかがわかりません

https://readouble.com/laravel/5.7/ja/routing.html
このドキュメントも読んでみたのですが $request を使った書き方が

```
 /**
 * 送信されたリクエストの処理
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->route()->named('profile')) {
        //
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

しか書かれていなくて route() というメソッドも読んでいないです

そもそも Request というのはプリミティブクラスじゃないんでしょうか
そこにおそらくユーザ定義？の user() というメソッドが定義されてる？のが訳がわからないです…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

私はLaravelは一度も使ったことがないですが、

[Authentication - Laravel - The PHP Framework For Web Artisans](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication) に

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // $request->user() returns an instance of the authenticated user...
}
```

とあります。

解説には

> Alternatively, once a user is authenticated, you may access the authenticated user via an Illuminate\Http\Request instance. Remember, type-hinted classes will automatically be injected into your controller methods:

とあるので、処理は

`Illuminate\Http\Request` の中だと思います。
おそらくその中というのは下記だと思います。

https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/Request.php#L516

おそらく同じことですが、laravelリポジトリ内から辿りたいなら下記です。

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L516

ちなみに参考になさっているページ [ルーティング 5.7 Laravel](https://readouble.com/laravel/5.7/ja/routing.html) 下部には

> Licensed by MIT License. Copyright at Taylor Otwell(Original) and Hirohisa kawase(Translation), 2018.
> ドキュメントメンテナンス期間は終了しました。

とあります。

同じくメンテナンスが終了しているようですが、

[API認証 5.8 Laravel](https://readouble.com/laravel/5.8/ja/api-authentication.html) に質問者さんと同じ用法の

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function(Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

がありました。`use Illuminate\Http\Request;` なので、私が上げたリンクのものが中身だと思います。

Comment: user() は laravel 固有の組み込みの認証メソッドだったんですね。どこかのコントローラーに user() が定義してあるのかと思っていました。